# Add missing dates to a Multiindex from a dt series

Tags: python, pandas

Attempting to add missing datetimes to a MultiIndex. Datetimes are in a series (named 'ndx').
Simply doing this does not work:

```
df.reindex(index=ndx, level=0, fill_value=np.nan)
```

What I have:

```
                   Column1
Date       Name
2016-11-01 AAA     25
           BBB     26
2016-11-07 CCC     27
```

What I'd like:

```
                   Column1
Date       Name
2016-11-01 AAA     25
           BBB     26
2016-11-02 NaN     NaN
2016-11-03 NaN     NaN
2016-11-04 NaN     NaN
2016-11-05 NaN     NaN
2016-11-06 NaN     NaN
2016-11-07 CCC     27
```

Is this possible without flattening the index into columns? If not, what's the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: This won't reproduce exactly what you've shown but quick and dirty `df.unstack().asfreq('D').stack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, only first convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
ndx = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2016-11-01','2016-11-07'))

df = ndx.to_frame('Date').merge(df.reset_index(), how='left').set_index(['Date','Name'])
print (df)
                 Column1
Date       Name         
2016-11-01 AAA      25.0
           BBB      26.0
2016-11-02 NaN       NaN
2016-11-03 NaN       NaN
2016-11-04 NaN       NaN
2016-11-05 NaN       NaN
2016-11-06 NaN       NaN
2016-11-07 CCC      27.0
```